# Python loop through list starting at index

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I am looking for a more pythonic way to loop though a list starting an an index then return the values contained in sub-lists eg:

```
values = [[1,2], [2], [1,3,4]]
n=1
for i, item in enumerate(values[n:]):
    i += n
    if i < len(values):
        for sub_value in values[i]:
            print("index: "+str(i)+ " list: "+str(item)+ " sub value: "+str(sub_value))
```

The code works as intended but is pretty ugly, any ideas to simplify it?

Comment: Why are you doing `i += n`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I am pulling out the i+nth item from the main list, otherwise i starts at zero and I get the wrong sub-values

Comment: `oop though a list starting an an index then return the values contained in sub-lists` This contradicts with your program

Comment: This code looks a bit... off... is this your desired output?: 
`index: 1 list: [2] sub value: 2
index: 2 list: [1, 3, 4] sub value: 1
index: 2 list: [1, 3, 4] sub value: 3
index: 2 list: [1, 3, 4] sub value: 4`

Comment: @Hybrid, yes that's is the output I'm after - I just realised may be cleaner to return the sub-lists as they are ie [2] and then [1,3, 4] and then just iterate over them.

Comment: I see... is there a way you can explain what you are trying to do a bit more clearly? As @DonSmythe asked, it doesn't make sense to do `i +=n`. Also, the rest of the code seems to be a bit confused. Let me know your goal, and I can try my best to give you an optimized solution.

Comment: @Hybrid Thanks. I want to iterate over a list starting at a specific index, then obtain the values from a sub-list contained at that location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are trying to achieve.If you want to print a flat list of the items from index 1 you could do this:

```
[item for sublist in values[1:] for item in sublist]
```

which produces:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a swing here and guess that you are trying to make a simple python function that loops through a list and prints out every element in the sublists. Here is the easiest way to do it:

```
def get_sublists(start=0):
    values = [[1,2], [2], [1,3,4]] 
    index = start 
    item = 0
    for value in values[index:]: 
        for sub_value in value: 
            print("Item: %s // Index: %s // List: %s // Sub Value: %s" % (item, index, values[index], sub_value)) 
            item += 1
        index += 1

get_sublists(1)
```

This will print out the following:

```
Item: 0 // Index: 1 // List: [2] // Sub Value: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Item: 1 // Index: 2 // List: [1, 3, 4] // Sub Value: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Item: 2 // Index: 2 // List: [1, 3, 4] // Sub Value: 3                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Item: 3 // Index: 2 // List: [1, 3, 4] // Sub Value: 4
```

I am not 100% sure about the question because it is a bit ambigous, so let me know if you have any further modifications.

Comment: your comments made me think a bit more about what I was trying to do and I came up with this:    def getSubLists(start, values):
    for i, item in enumerate(values[start:]):
        for value in item:
            print(str(value))

values = [[1,2], [2], [1,3,4]]
getSubLists(1, values)  This way I can start my iteration at a specific location

Comment: Oh, I finally understand. In that case, you can use @craighagerman's solution since it uses List Comprehension, which is very efficient. If you want a more detailed output, you can use the function I provided above.